# Latest version of kafka_2.12-3.0.0 not running with zookeeper

Tags: apache-kafka

I have several versions of kafka installed: kafka_2.12-2.8.0 and kafka_2.12_3.0.0

I followed the procedure outlined here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-install-and-run-apache-kafka-on-windows/

this works fine for the older version of kafka but not the latest version. kafka starts then shutsdown. I am interested to see if anyone has had this experience.

Comment: FWIW it's easiest to just [run it under WSL2](https://www.confluent.io/en-gb/blog/set-up-and-run-kafka-on-windows-linux-wsl-2/)

Comment: Yes, [several people have had the same issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-kafka+windows)